# Replace text on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for some code that will allow me to click a button (Button with value "Next") which will then replace some of the code I have on my page with new code. This is my current code, I need to replace everything after the score counter. Apologies for the sloppy code, I'm pretty new to this.

```
<body>
<p>Score: <span id="counter">0</span></p><br/>

<p>1) What colour is this?</p><br />

<p><img style= "margin: 0 auto;" src="colour1.png" width="70%"></p><br /><br />


<p><button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Almond White</button><br>
<button id="score" onClick="showDiv02(); this.disabled = 'true';">Raspberry Diva</button><br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Melon Sorbet</button><br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Gentle Lavender</button><br></p>


<div id="answer1" style="display:none;" class="wronganswer">&#10007;</div>
<div id="answer2" style="display:none;" class="rightanswer">&#10003;</div>


<p><input type="button" name="next2" value="Next" onClick="showDiv2()" /></p>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Maria dear its really a sloppy code but trying to understand ur requirement :)

Comment: Put your content in a div so you can reset the div content.

Comment: @AndyHolmes I want to replace the question: "What colour is this?" and the answer buttons with a new question and new answers. I haven't tried anything yet, I couldn't find anything in my searches that looked like what I wanted.

Comment: @FlorentHemmi How would I reset the div content?

Comment: Look at @Neel answer. Each question are wrapped in a div so the function can hide and show the correct div/question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below fiddle i am not sure its perfect u want or not but just tried

```
<body>
<p>Score: <span id="counter">0</span></p><br/>
<div id="div1">
<p>1) What colour is this?</p><br />

<p><img style= "margin: 0 auto;" src="colour1.png" width="70%"></p><br /><br />


<p><button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Almond White</button><br>
<button id="score" onClick="showDiv02(); this.disabled = 'true';">Raspberry Diva</button><br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Melon Sorbet</button><br>
    <button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">Gentle Lavender</button><br></p>
</div>
    <div id="div2" hidden>
        1) What car is this?</p><br />

<p><img style= "margin: 0 auto;" src="colour1.png" width="70%"></p><br /><br />


<p><button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">abc</button><br>
<button id="score" onClick="showDiv02(); this.disabled = 'true';">def</button><br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">rtrt</button><br>
    <button id="none" onClick="showDiv01()">xyz</button><br></p>
    </div>

<div id="answer1" style="display:none;" class="wronganswer">&#10007;</div>
<div id="answer2" style="display:none;" class="rightanswer">&#10003;</div>


<p><input type="button" id="btn" name="next2" value="Next" onClick="showDiv2()" /></p>
</body>

$('#btn').click( function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxyQG/

Comment: Thanks guys this is exactly what I was after, but previewed from DW in Safari and Firefox and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: well i have firefox and it works for me :) what does DW means? i dont know so asking

Comment: @Neel Sorry, it means Dreamweaver

Comment: ok Maria but its working in firefox sorry but i dont have any idea of dreamweaver :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the text on button click.  I checked you button have an `onClick="showDiv2()"`

So try like this (for an example)

```
function showDiv2 () {
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "";  //empty the value
}
```

Here is example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa563/), I have create when you click next the counter will be replaced.

Comment: @Neel I have just shown an simple example, where the `counter` 0 is replaced when NEXT button is clicked.  This is working in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is place **all** the content you want to replace inside a `<div>`.

then you will want to give that div an `id` attribute.

e.g.

```
<div id="yourID">
    HTML CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Then in javascript, you would need to create a function that would fire on an `onclick` event.

Markup:

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeContent('yourID', '<div>OtherHTML</div>')" value="NEXT" />
```

when you have these 2 components, you will want to make a script that will execute your function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeContent(id, html) {
        //Get the element that needs it's contents replaced.
        var container = document.getElementById(id);

        //insert new HTML onclick.
        container.innerHTML = html;
    }

</script>
```

This is a simple example of what you need.
You could externalize this javascript in a seperate file.

If you want to do this, you will need to include the script in the `<head>` of your html document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js.js"></script>
```

Because this will load before any of the DOM will have been loaded, you will get errors.

To solve this, the new contents of the file will be:

**js.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

    function changeContent(id, html) {
        //Get the element that needs it's contents replaced.
        var container = document.getElementById(id);

        //insert new HTML onclick.
        container.innerHTML = html;
    }

}
```

This should work for you in this scenario.

Hope this helped

‐ Sid